# Unhandled Exception error in .NET Maui, when a catch is provided

Tags: maui

So I tried to make an alert appear when the purchase button is clicked, however, now when I try get to navigate to the page that contains that code, I get this error:

```cs
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
    UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    };
#endif
```

This is my current code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
    
namespace AlexaTrees.Views
{
    public partial class PurchaseATreePage : ContentPage
    {
        public PurchaseATreePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnPurchaseButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Display the alert when the button is clicked
                DisplayAlert("Purchase Confirmation", "Yay! Your tree has been purchased, and the Amazon is now safer.", "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the button where the function is called:

```xml
<Button Text="Purchase" BackgroundColor="LightGray" WidthRequest="200" CornerRadius="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Clicked="OnPurchaseButtonClicked"></Button>
```

Comment: The code doesn't look like it should be throwing an exception. What else happens in the `OnPurchaseButtonClicked()` event handler? Is that all? Generally, the `DisplayAlert()` call should be awaited, so you need to make the event handler `async` and `await DisplayAlert();`.

Comment: Currently, I can't even click on the page where this code is located. I also made it async but that still doesn't work.

Comment: You're not showing any error, you're only pointing to the location where it happens. Can you please show the actual exception and stack trace (as text)? I don't think that the problem is related to the code you're showing, if you cannot even get to the page. What else do you have? Please show the relevant bits of code and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No errors appear in the error list, I just get redirected to the App.g.i.ca page in Visual Studio, and the error that I provided is highlighted. Otherwise nothing else is shown.

Comment: The debugger usually opens an exception dialog, or when the app crashes, you can see the stack trace and the exception in the Output window. The error list is useless for runtime errors, it's only used for compile time and linker errors.

Comment: "i can't even click on the page" - what does this mean?  Does the exception happen before the page appears?  Does the exception go away if you remove the button?

Comment: When I click to navigate to the page containing this code, the code breaks before the page appears.

Comment: then the problem is obviously not in the event handler.  You need to look at the exception object and stack trace to find the origin of the problem.

Comment: Comment out that line of code. Problem still happens, right? It isn’t that line.